# fltk: failed to resolve GlutWindow

Tags: rust, fltk

I'm trying to follow example of fltk application which uses openGl, but the build is not functioning:

```
    let app = app::App::default();
let mut win = window::GlutWindow::default().with_size(800, 600);
win.set_mode(enums::Mode::Opengl3);
win.end();
win.show();

unsafe {
    let gl = glow::Context::from_loader_function(|s| {
        win.get_proc_address(s) as *const _
    });
```

I get: failed to resolve: could not find `GlutWindow` in `window`.

I'm using fltk version 1

Thank you

p.s. I'm using Rust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your imports which are missing from that snippet.
Also if you’re not enabling the `enable-glwindow` feature, you should, try changing your Cargo.toml to include the missing feature:

```
[dependencies]
fltk = { version = "1", features = ["enable-glwindow"] }
```